# ui.bootstrap.collapse - one collapse for each row in a table column - open only the collapse which has been clicked (not all of them)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using ui-bootstrap.collapse inside a table with dynamic data from a JSON API. Two of the multiple columns contain collapsed partials for each of its rows.

When I'm clicking on one of the icons to toggle that particular partial, every partial of the entire column open up.

Same issue when I'm trying to close the partial again - any of the icons work (not only the one of that particular partial).

I'm suspecting that I got to add a unique id or something like this to each of the partials to make one only that particular one pop up. But I'm not able to get this working.

Can any one point me in the right direction please?

Here is some of my code (I replaced the dynamic data with static data to make it simpler:

```
...
<tbody ng-repeat="url in urls">
    <tr>
      <td>{{url.url}}<span class="pull-right" ng-click="toggleUrl()">&#x25BC;</span></td>
      <td>{{url.title}}</td>
      <td>{{url.traffic}}<span class="pull-right" ng-click="toggleTraffic()">&#x25BC;</span></td>
    </tr>

    <!-- urlCollapsed -->
    <tr collapse="!urlCollapsed">
      <td colspan="4" style="background-color: pink">
      </td>
    </tr>
...
```

and a working plunker with the entire code: http://plnkr.co/edit/e4UldAFjjIr26Il73C88?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass url or some unique field to toggleUrl() method and then at the method make specific variable for each roe partial nd make them true. Accordingly you'll have to mak specific  partial for each nd shoe them accordingly on ng-show.
Something like this

```
$scope.toggleUrl = function (url) {
  if (url === '/1') {           
    $scope.url1Collapsed = !$scope.url1Collapsed;
  } else {
    $scope.urlCollapsed = !$scope.urlCollapsed;
  }
};
```

and on page

```
<tr collapse="!url1Collapsed">
    <td colspan="4" style="background-color: pink">partial 1</td>
</tr>
<tr collapse="!urlCollapsed">
    <td colspan="4" style="background-color: pink"> partial 0</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - I forgot to mention that my table gets its data from a data heavy JSON API, so making specific partials for each is not really an option for me.

But at the same time I've tried to pass an url as you suggested to the toggleUrl() and changed it 
1. to toggleUrl(url.url), which displays toggleUrl(url.url) in the DOM, which doesn't work and then
2. to toggleUrl({{url.url}}) which displays me toggleUrl("/") in the DOM (which is good), but the toggle doesn't work anymore